# HorizontalScrollView as gallery, when touch make image bigger

Tags: android, zooming, gallery

i am trying to implement gallery using `HorizontalScrollView`.

When user click image image it should "grow up" to show this image like this: (i will have images from drawable folder)

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvBWn.png)

Comment: Try to open Bigger Image in Popup.

Comment: Use `Gallery` instead of `HorizontalListView`. Although `Gallery` is depreciated but its working like a charm...Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PopupWindow. In the layout just put an imageView and fill it with the clicked image.

Check this out http://mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/